# How to use a select pivot query to update two different tables

Tags: sql-server

I would like to update data in two different table however based on select query using pivot I'm unsure how to go about to do the update query.

See query I have below:

```
UPDATE [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseTank] SET OpenDip = 0.00, CloseDip = 0.00 WHERE WhenDate = GETDATE() AND TankID = 'BW-TK-DSL1'
UPDATE [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] SET OpenReading = 0.00, CloseReading = 0.00 WHERE [Date] = GETDATE() AND TankID = 'BW-TK-DSL1' AND NozzleNo = 1
UPDATE [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] SET OpenReading = 0.00, CloseReading = 0.00 WHERE [Date] = GETDATE() AND TankID = 'BW-TK-DSL1' AND NozzleNo = 2
```

**SELECT QUERY:**

```
SELECT 
    [Date], T.TankID, [OpenDip], [CloseDip], [ORNozzle1], [CRNozzle1], [ORNozzle2], [CRNozzle2]
FROM [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseTank] T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [TankID], [Date], SUM([1]) AS [ORNozzle1], SUM([2]) AS [ORNozzle2]
    FROM [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] 
    PIVOT
    ( 
        MAX (OpenReading)
        FOR [NozzleNo] IN ([1], [2])
    ) AS P     
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[Date])='2019-11-09'
    GROUP BY [TankID], [Date]
) AS A  
    ON [T].[TankID] = [A].[TankID]
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [TankID], SUM([1]) AS [CRNozzle1], SUM([2]) AS [CRNozzle2]
    FROM [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] 
    PIVOT
    ( 
        MAX (CloseReading)
        FOR [NozzleNo] IN ([1], [2])
    ) AS P     
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [Date])='2019-11-09'
    GROUP BY [TankID]
) AS B  
    ON [T].[TankID] = [B].[TankID]
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Whendate) = '2019-11-09'
```

**QUERY RESULTS:**

[image]

**TABLE DATA:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't mind, I cleaned up the formatting of your queries to make the question a little more readable. You should add a little more information to the question such as what have you tried and why it isn't working. From my understanding you're trying to UPDATE the OpenCloseTank and OpenCloseNozzle tables fields with the example UPDATE statements you provided based on the SELECT query you provided after it?

Comment: The select query is just display the data, however I would like to then openclosetank and openclosenozzle table fields shown in the example. The problem I’m having based on the select statement using pivot when updating the table fields how would I get those parameters seeing that it’s one row for the where clause from what’s displayed in the query results picture

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure to understand your question but if you are looking at doing and UPDATE from a SELECT, then you may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server).

Comment: short answers that don't provide much detail should be avoided.  It's better to capture some of the details from the other post into your answer here, or provide some of your own details about how you'd solve the problem.  Thanks!